# Whats the probability that the component B1 fails given that the system fails

Tags: probability, statistics

I am really stuck at some probability exercise. Given that the system fails, what is the probability that the component B1 fails? The circuit is as follows:

[Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKJX7.png)

The probability that the system fails is: P=A'*B' = 0.01*0.02 = 0.0297. 
The probability that A fails is P(A'|System failure) = 0.01/0.0297 = 0,332

I can't figure out how to get the probability that B1 fails given that the system fails. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something's wrong. In order for Sys B to fail, _both_ B1 and B2 (in parallel) have to fail.

Comment: I know that the probability that B works is 0.98 so that B fails must be 1 - P(B works) that gives us: 1 - 0.98 = 0.02.?

Comment: You're in a tangle. New approach. Make a Venn Diagram with A, B1, B2. Shade in _exactly_ the areas that lead to system failure. For exmp, Syst will fail of all 3 components fail. What else? Maybe you're not thinking correctly about the difference btw parallel and series connections. [Erasing one of my earlier comments, so we won't get busted for 'chatting' in Comments].

Comment: I really don't get it. Do I have to take away something in my equation?

Answer (score 2):

The system fails if either subsystem $A$ fails or subsystem $B$  fails,
i.e. $P(\text{system fails})=A' + B1'B2' - A'B1'B2'$

Since each component failure is independent, P($B' \cap \text{system fails} ) = B1'A' +  B1'B2'A$

$P(B1' |\text{system fails}) = \dfrac{P(B1'\cap \text{system fails})}{P(\text{system fails})} = \dfrac{0.1\times0.01 + 0.1\times0.2\times0.99}{0.01 + 0.1\times0.2- 0.01\times0.1\times0.2} =\dfrac{2.08}{2.98}$

**Added list of cases where system fails** (lower case represents failure of a component)

a **b1** B2
a **b1**b2
a B1 B2
a B1 b2
A **b1**b2

Comment: Quibble: $P(Sys fail) = P(A') + P(B_1' \cap B_2') - P(A'\cap B_1'\cap B_2').$ Anyhow, right track (+1)

Comment: I'll add a list (there are only $5$ cases ! It'll be clear then.

Comment: In case anyone cares: my simulation with $10^8$ iterations gives 0.698, which agrees with my (pre-morning-coffee) computation.

Comment: There are $2^3 = 8$ cases with probabilities that add to 1. Look at Venn Diagram.

Comment: @BruceET: You are right, but for the question I have considered the restricted sample space where system failure occurs.

Comment: @PureRushh: If we take all $8$ cases, we'll get a probability of 100%, but I have taken only the $5$  cases that lead to system failure.

Comment: @trueblueanil Ahh so we are missing A B1 b2, A b1 B2, A B1 B2?

Comment: Yes, but I have spotted an obvious  error, thanks to @BruceET (it's 1:30 am here) so hopefully I'll get it right now,  and go to sleep !